# Classify a number according to defined bins

Tags: r

Given a number x and a vector of bins:

```
x <- 7
bins <- seq(0, 10,2)

> bins
[1]  0  2  4  6  8 10
```

How can I get the bin to which x belongs?
In this case the result would be the bin starting with `6` and ending with `8` because `6 < x < 8`.

To further exemplify I'd like to construct a function that does something similar to this:

```
>classify_string(x,bins)
 "6-8"
```

Or:

```
>classify(x,bins)
 6
```

Comment: Have a look at `?cut`

Comment: `classify_string` is most like `cut()` and `classify` is most like `findInterval()`

Comment: Yep! Those are the functions that I was looking for, thanks.